# Using “which” in this sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

> An immovable property may be subjected to a servitude by virtue of which the owner of such property is bound.

I would like to know how “which” is being used in this sentence and what it refers to. Thank you

Comment: It's a relative pronoun and the object of the preposition _of_, which modifies the noun _virtue_, which is the object of the preposition _by_. The entire phrase _by virtue of which_ is pied-piped to the front of the relative clause. It means the owner of such property is bound by the servitude. _Which_ refers to the servitude.

Comment: Could I change which to what?

Comment: No, I don't think you can. "by virtue of" means "because of", and "because of what" would not be idiomatic.